# Patching(mocking) forms form in django tests

Tags: python, django, testing, mocking, python-mock

I tried to mock form with mock.patch and can`t. I have this code

forms.py

```
class CreatePostForm(object):
    pass
```

views.py:

```
from forms import CreatePostForm

def doit():
    print CreatePostForm()
```

and I want to to test this view in isolation. I tried to patch form with mock.patch and i wrote something like that:

tests.py:

```
from mock import patch

import views

with patch('forms.CreatePostForm') as Form:
    views.doit()
```

I tried to google for solution and find nothing

**Answered:** thanks @dstanek for good answer and good sample of code

Comment: http://williamjohnbert.com/2011/07/how-to-unit-testing-in-django-with-mocking-and-patching/

Comment: @catherine I tried your approach but it doesn`t work for me

Comment: @MaxKharandziuk can you elaborate on "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use patch you specify the target of the object you want to mock. This is usually the place where it is imported, not where it is defined.

This is because by the time your test runs the `views` module has already been imported. If you are importing the class like I'm doing in my example below then the `views` module will contain a reference to the `forms.CreatePostForm`. So changing `forms.CreatePostForm` would not change this reference. Things would be different if you imported the module as specified `forms.CreatePostForm` in your view.

I've included an extremely minimal example below.

forms.py

```
class CreatePostForm(object):
    pass
```

views.py:

```
from forms import CreatePostForm

def doit():
    print CreatePostForm()
```

tests.py:

```
from mock import patch

import views

with patch('views.CreatePostForm') as Form:
    views.doit()
```

Comment: extremelly good answer. You did correct and really beatiful sample of the code

Comment: +1 the namepsace for `CreatePostForm` is in views. Patch at the location it is used (based on import). http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#where-to-patch